# Class AB amplifier sizing

Tags: amplifier, class-ab

I have simulated a class AB amplifier as shown in the attached diagram. Its working pretty fine at 5kHz and 500mV input signal.

[image]

However, the simulation fails when I try to change the requirements to fit the specifications of my project which are:

- 19 kHz
- 5V AC input
- 5mH load inductance
- 9 ohm DC resistance of the load

How can I best size the components to fit my specifications - what are the equations can I use?

Comment: Lower the T1 gain by decreasing Rc/Re ratio.

Comment: Without any negative feedback the high output level distortion will be high.

Comment: The specifications of the project do not include some very important information that is necessary to design an amplifier, such as:  maximum output power, maximum input signal voltage (peak-to-peak) to give maximum output power, the minimum permitted input impedance (or impedance of the signal source at the amplifier input), power supply voltage rails (positive & negative rails, or just one rail), bandwidth ie: half-power (-3dB) frequency points (both low and high), & maximum permitted distortion at maximum rated power.   Is there a step-response specification (input is a square wave)?

Answer (score 0):

With such a load (9 Ohm + 5 mH), it would be difficult (power) to meet your requirements at 19 kHz.

[image]

[image]